# Definição de roles ao estilo Wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soa

Estou planejando a arquitetura de um projeto pessoal a ser implementado usando Rails. Nele, eu gostaria que fosse possível modificar facilmente as regras de acesso dos usuários, como é feito no wordpress. Sei que existe o cancan pra fazer isso, mas acredito que não serviria para a minha necessidade. É uma aplicação orientada a serviços. Cada usuário vai ter permissão de acesso somente a determinados serviços. Pensei em implementar uma solução minha, específica pra essa necessidade, que permita que o administrador da aplicação modifique facilmente as permissões de acesso dos usuários através de uma interface administrativa. Alguém saberia me indicar uma solução pra isso?

Comment: Por que você acredita que o Cancan não serviria? Existe também o https://github.com/elabs/pundit. Ambos podem ajudar a implementar uma solução p/ sua necessidade pois são bem básicos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, não tem segredo, é ir pelo básico, passo-a-passo:

1. Listar os usuários e os sua função (admin, convidado, estudante, etc...)
2. Ao clicar no usuário poder atualizar seu função.
3. Ao visitar alguma página verificar se o usuário tem a permissão para visualizar a página.

O modelo de usuário deverá ter um field "role" que será verificado ao usuário for visualizar ou utilizar alguma coisa que necessite de autorização.

Por exemplo em sua view você poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
<% if is_admin(@user) %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post) %>
<% end %>
```

Dependendo da complexidade exigida você pode ir incrementando o que nescessitar.